# Downloading file from WebMethod in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I am using following method to download the file from server to the client

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]       
public static bool AddEtag(string pwd, int id)
{
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.csv";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileData.FileName + "\"");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

but I am not able to download the file at client side.Can it be done using handlers. Any links would be fine